# Ubuntu 20 Pro and downloading specific packages

Tags: package-management

I have a Ubuntu 20 desktop that has a Pro subscription.  Can I just download a specific package without installing it?  I want to test the package on my VM before installing it on my Desktop PC.

It is a specific ftp package since there is a vulnerability notice on it.

https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5175-1

Thanks in advance,
Leo

Comment: Do you mean just like running `apt download ntp` from a command line?

Comment: never tried download instead of install, does this work?

Comment: Oh wow, never used just download instead of install.  That worked perfectly from the host on the Ubuntu Pro subscription.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: One thing to remember, after you download just the `.deb` file to test out, it is probably best to install it by doing `sudo apt install ./filename.deb` that way it will tell `apt` to also download all the dependencies needed.

Comment: For sure.  It worked perfectly.  Thanks again!